# How can I get Mocha's Unicode output to display properly in a Windows console?

Tags: powershell, unicode, mocha.js, windows-console

When I run [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/), it tries to show a check mark or an X for a passing or a failing test run, respectively. I've seen great-looking screenshots of Mocha's output. But those screenshots were all taken on Macs or Linux. In a console window on Windows, these characters both show up as a nondescript empty-box character, the classic "huh?" glyph:

[image: Screenshot of Mocha in the Windows console, with a box character instead of the expected check mark]

If I highlight the text in the console window and copy it to the clipboard, I do see actual Unicode characters; I can paste the fancy characters into a textbox in a Web browser and they render just fine (✔, ✖). So the Unicode output is getting to the console window just fine; the problem is that the console window isn't displaying those characters properly.

How can I fix this so that all of Mocha's output (including the ✔ and ✖) displays properly in a Windows console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: this issue has now been fixed. Starting from Mocha 1.7.0, fallbacks are used for symbols that don't exist in default console fonts (√ instead of ✔, × instead of ✖, etc.). It's not as pretty as it could be, but it surely beats empty-box placeholder symbols.

For details, see the related pull request: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/641

Comment: That's actually a better, more proactive answer than mine -- it makes it Just Work, everywhere. Thanks for making that happen!

Comment: No probs mate :) Let's rock on in Windows with Mocha now!

Answer (score 25):

By pasting the characters into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), I was able to figure out that they were ['HEAVY CHECK MARK' (U+2714)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/index.htm) and ['HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X' (U+2716)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2716/index.htm). It looks like neither character is supported in any of the console fonts (Consolas, Lucida Console, or Raster Fonts) that are available in Windows 7. In fact, out of *all* the fonts that ship with Windows 7, only a handful support these characters (Meiryo, Meiryo UI, MS Gothic, MS Mincho, MS PGothic, MS PMincho, MS UI Gothic, and Segoe UI Symbol). The ones starting with "MS" are all fixed-width (monospace) fonts, but they all look awful at the font sizes typical of a console. And the others are out, since the console requires fixed-width fonts.

So you'll need to download a font. I like [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) -- it's free, it looks good at console sizes, it's easy to tell the `0` from the `O` and the `1` from the `I` from the `l`, and it's got all kinds of fancy Unicode symbols, including the check and X that Mocha uses.

[image: Sample of the DejaVu Sans Mono font]

Unfortunately, it's a bit of a pain to install a new console font, but it's doable. (Steps adapted from [this post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingConsolasAsTheWindowsConsoleFont.aspx), but extended to include the non-obvious subtleties of `000`.)

Steps:

1. [Download the DejaVu fonts.](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download) Unzip the files. Go into the "ttf" directory you just unzipped, select all the files, right-click and "Install".
2. Run Regedit, and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`.
3. Add a new string value. Give it a name that's a string of zeroes one longer than the longest string of zeroes that's already there. For example, on my Windows 7 install, there's already a value named `0` and one named `00`, so I had to name the new one `000`.
4. Double-click on your new value, and set its value to `DejaVu Sans Mono`.
5. Reboot. (Yes, this step is necessary, at least on OSes up to and including Windows 7.)
6. Now you can open a console window, open the window menu, go to Defaults > Font tab, and "DejaVu Sans Mono" should be available in the Font list box. Select it and OK.

Now Mocha's output will display in all its glory.

[image: Screenshots of Mocha output displaying correctly in a Windows console]

Comment: The reboot was unrequired for me on Windows 7

Comment: No reboot required in Windows 10 either