# How to add color to symbol objects?

Tags: powershell

I am looking to provide users with a size list that also compares against a threshold. if threshold is exceeded, that should generate a RED X mark. otherwise, if threshold is not exceeded that should generate a green checkmark

i found [this](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-green-checkmarks-in-console-output) code:

```
$greenCheck = @{
  Object = [Char]8730
  ForegroundColor = 'Green'
  NoNewLine = $true
  }
Write-Host @greenCheck
```

that is fantastic but requires write-host...i cant just call it like this in other words `@greenCheck`

> The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in
>   an expression. '@greenCheck' can be used only as an argument to a
>   command. To reference variables in an expression use '$greenCheck'.

i found this other code [here](https://communary.net/2015/11/08/quick-tip-easy-access-to-special-symbols/)

```
$symbols = [PSCustomObject] @{
    SMILEY_WHITE = ([char]9786)
    SMILEY_BLACK = ([char]9787)
    GEAR = ([char]9788)
    HEART = ([char]9829)
    DIAMOND = ([char]9830)
    CLUB = ([char]9827)
    SPADE = ([char]9824)
    CIRCLE = ([char]8226)
    NOTE1 = ([char]9834)
    NOTE2 = ([char]9835)
    MALE = ([char]9794)
    FEMALE = ([char]9792)
    YEN = ([char]165)
    COPYRIGHT = ([char]169)
    PI = ([char]960)
    TRADEMARK = ([char]8482)
    CHECKMARK = ([char]8730)
}
```

this one is perfect! but it doesnt have colors. how can i add colors to the object?
also, is there more symbols i can find like an X mark? or i would have to just use good ol' 'X' char?

Comment: @LotPings is that missing a square bracket at the end?

Comment: @LotPings ohh nvm...very interesting syntax...  do you know if there is a way to make the symbols bigger, i.e. resize them?

Comment: @LotPings fascinating. now my console outputs all red lol.what is the use of 0x1b?

Comment: @LotPings what would i use in the fall update? 027? youre referring ot PS7 right?

Comment: @LotPings oh i meant changing the size of the actual character/symbol, because i am sending this as emails and i want the symbol to not be so tiny

Comment: @LotPings is there a way to incorporate this `"$([char]0x1b)[92m$([char]8730) $([char]0x1b)[91m×"` in the pscutomobject $symbols above? i.e. it'd be a lot easier to call a symbol from the pscutomobject like this: `$symbols.CHECKMARK`. how do i add the color inside the pscutomobject? `CHECKMARK = $([char]0x1b)[92m$([char]8730)` like that?

Comment: Take a look at `Get-PsReadLineOption`, IIRC you can reset color/attributes with `"$([char]0x1b)[0m"`

Comment: @LotPings that reset code is very useful thanks!

Comment: @LotPings i looked at Get-PsReadLineOption. not sure what im supposed ot make from it...it just lists some information regarding colors like cyan dak magenta etc... and other symbols, like ;:,.[]{}()/\|^&*-=+'"–—― available...

Comment: That*s the point it showa the colors and how to use the ESC codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a green checkmark and a red x try: `"$([char]0x1b)[92m$([char]8730) $([char]0x1b)[91m×"` 
[image]

Some Links:
❌ https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10-october-2018-update/cross-mark/
[How can I get Mocha's Unicode output to display properly in a Windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817926/how-can-i-get-mochas-unicode-output-to-display-properly-in-a-windows-console)

[Ansi escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

The [new Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/) allows change of the font size like other apps with CTRL+Wheel among other goodies.

Comment: wait...is that cross mark different from the X? if so, what is the char code for it?

Comment: It is different, but it depends on the font used to contain that glyph, the Lucida Console I use does not have it.

Comment: i see. i am sending this stuff in a psobject which gets sent as an HTML email, so dont want to have user issues if things are required, unless i can add the font as part of the code to obtain it?

Comment: Surf that emojipedia site to see other emojis and dependencies.

Comment: ok, question. how can i add this code to a pscutomobject, i.e. `$symbols = [PSCustomObject] @{
    CHECKMARK = $([char]0x1b)[92m$([char]8730);
    'X_MARK' = $([char]0x1b)[91m×) }`

Comment: figured it out: `$symbols = [PSCustomObject] @{ CHECKMARK = "$([char]0x1b)[92m$([char]8730) $([char]0x1b)[0m"; XMARK = "$([char]0x1b)[91m× $([char]0x1b)[0m" }`